# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'defined' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

I'm using php 5.4 version. I got the problem after I upload my Joomla cms folder from my localhost to my webhosting.

This is the code

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');

// Create shortcuts to some parameters.
$params  = $this->item->params;
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
$urls    = json_decode($this->item->urls);
$canEdit = $params->get('access-edit');
$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$info    = $params->get('info_block_position', 0);
JHtml::_('behavior.caption');
$useDefList = ($params->get('show_modify_date') || $params->get('show_publish_date') ||          $params->get('show_create_date')
|| $params->get('show_hits') || $params->get('show_category') || $params-   >get('show_parent_category') || $params->get('show_author'));

?>
```

I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'defined' (T_STRING) in /home/u854215895/public_html/templates/realestate/html/com_content/article/default.php on line 1

Please help... Thanks

Comment: are you on windows ? if so, make sure your file has unix ending line character `\n` and not the windows `\r\n` ones.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space from here

```
$params-   >get('show_parent_category')
       --^--
```

So it goes like this.

```
$useDefList = ($params->get('show_modify_date') || $params->get('show_publish_date') ||          $params->get('show_create_date')
        || $params->get('show_hits') || $params->get('show_category') || $params->get('show_parent_category') || $params->get('show_author'));
```